# How to compare same keys values from two different dict with percentage

Tags: python

Trying to compare same keys values from two different dict, If second dict values are bigger by 50% than first dict values then output should show different keys values only.

```
Example:
first={'a': '1000', 'b': '2000', 'c': '2400'}
second={'a': '1000', 'b': '3000', 'c': '5000'}
new dict output should be {'c': '5000'} # c is 50% bigger from first dict value
```

how to do this comparison

below code shows if bigger only without percentage , how to get if second values are bigger by 50%

```
print(dict((k, second[k])for k in second if second[k] > first[k]))
```

Comment: Your first dict has 3 keys. How do you decide which key to print? Or you just want the compare highest with lowest values?

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Your values in the dict are strings. Therefore, you should recast them to int or float before making the comparison suggested by Rauch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that comparison by converting your strings to `int()`, and then compare one with the other times 1.5 inside a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#semantics) like:

#### Code:

```
{k: v for k, v in second.items() if int(v) > int(first[k]) * 1.5}
```

#### Test Code:

```
first={'a': '1000', 'b': '2000', 'c': '2400'}
second={'a': '1000', 'b': '3000', 'c': '5000'}
desired = {'c': '5000'} # c is 50% bigger from first dict value

print({k: v for k, v in second.items() if int(v) > int(first[k]) * 1.5})
```

#### Results:

```
{'c': '5000'}
```

Comment: in my code its float: first={'a': '0.1000', 'b': '0.2000', 'c': '0.2400'}
so I change it to float but now getting this error:TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
What this could be ?

Comment: @J87, Change the `int` to `float` if you need floats.  Also you can not vote until you have earned 15 reputation.  You can however `accept` the answer by checking the check mark under the vote buttons.  GL.